# Running a loop only if the value in column 16 of the active sheet is > 0

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, if-statement

This is my first experience writing any kind of code. I have been building a tracking system for my work in Excel. I have everything that I want currently working except I have a user form that when you click the command button it will look at my current inventory table (the table has a column (16 or P) that list how many cases of a product we should order to get us to our target stock quantity) and return a list of products and what we need to order. I have the form so it works, It populates a list box on the form with all the info that I want, but I would like it to exclude any rows that the table says we don't need to order. Here is my current code.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer
    Set ws = Worksheets("Current")
    lstProd.Clear
    lstProd.ColumnCount = 9
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To LastRow
        lstProd.AddItem ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
        lstProd.List(i - 1, 1) = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value
        lstProd.List(i - 1, 2) = ws.Cells(i, 3).Value
        lstProd.List(i - 1, 3) = "$" & Format(ws.Cells(i, 4).Value, "0.00")
        lstProd.List(i - 1, 4) = ws.Cells(i, 5).Value
        lstProd.List(i - 1, 5) = ws.Cells(i, 6).Value
        lstProd.List(i - 1, 6) = ws.Cells(i, 9).Value
        lstProd.List(i - 1, 7) = ws.Cells(i, 14).Value
        lstProd.List(i - 1, 8) = ws.Cells(i, 16).Value
    Next i
End Sub
```

I have tried a lot of `if ws.cells(i, 16) = "0"` and `For ws.cells.....` but always end up with different errors. I know it is something simple that I am missing but it has just eluded me so I thought I would break down and ask for help.

Comment: I am still a bit confused this is what I tried.  If ws.Cells(i, 16).Value2 > 0 Then lstProd.AddItem ws.Cells(i, 1).Value.   The code runs until it finds a zero in column 16 or untill it gets to the Lastline then it returns error "381 could not set the list property. Invalid property array index" Debug highlights the lstProd.list (i-1, 1) = ws.cells(i, 2).Value line.  Not sure if I am putting the line in the correct place or should I add it to the front of each line?

Answer (score 1):

If "the table says we don't need to order" means there is an empty cell in the checked range you may use the next code:

```
For i = 1 To LastRow
    If ws.Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then
        lstProd.AddItem ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
        lstProd.List(i - 1, 1) = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value
        lstProd.List(i - 1, 2) = ws.Cells(i, 3).Value
        lstProd.List(i - 1, 3) = "$" & Format(ws.Cells(i, 4).Value, "0.00")
        lstProd.List(i - 1, 4) = ws.Cells(i, 5).Value
        lstProd.List(i - 1, 5) = ws.Cells(i, 6).Value
        lstProd.List(i - 1, 6) = ws.Cells(i, 9).Value
        lstProd.List(i - 1, 7) = ws.Cells(i, 14).Value
        lstProd.List(i - 1, 8) = ws.Cells(i, 16).Value
    End if
Next i
```

If not, you must describe how those cells look/contain in order to make you understand "we don't need to order"...

Comment: Actually there is a formula that takes the target stock quantity and subtracts the current stock quantity to give the need to order quantity.  The number will all ways be Zero or higher. I am trying to get the VBA code to check to see if the need to order amount is zero, if so then don't list that row from the table to the list box, but I still want the code to continue running and checking each line after that so all products that need to be ordered show up in the list box.

Comment: What I was thinking would work is adding  "If ws.cells(i, 16) = 0 then next i"  I tried adding this after the "For i = 1 to LastRow" but this gives me the error " next without for".

Comment: I am checking the 16 column in the table and not the first column,  could this possibly be causing an issue?

Comment: @TheTracker: If the returned `lastRow` reflect your reality in the page you want to work, it should do what you want. I mean, the listbox will be loaded only with data from rows having  no/zero value in column A:A. But, are you sure that your formula does not return small amounts (ex. 0.12) which are rounded to 0 only for displaying? Was you the one who make that formula? Can you post it here?

Comment: @TheTracker: `"If ws.cells(i, 16) = 0 then ... next i` has no meaning in VBA. `If` must be ended with `End If`. And `For i = 1 to ....` must end with `Next i`.

Comment: The cells in the table are formatted to whole number Values. So there will never be a .**.  After further reading basically what I am after is a "Continue Loop" function. From what I have read, this does not exist in Excel VBA. I have thus tried a goto statement but when it finds a zero in column 16 the code stops running after the AddItem line. It says could not get the list property. Invalid Property. I don't know why because If I take the "If ws.Cells(i, 16).Value = 0 Then" line out it runs fine except it shows the rows with the 0 values.

Comment: The Formula for Column P is "F2-I2" F2 being the target Quantity to stock, and I2 is the current amount in stock. They are both in case Quantities.  I built a quick little userform and data table to test on ( so I didn't mess up what I already had.  I will Post the code for it in the next comment.

Comment: "Private Sub comClick_Click()"
"Dim ws As Worksheet"
"Dim i As Integer"
"Set ws = Worksheets("Data")"
"lstbox1.Clear"
"lstbox1.ColumnCount = 5"
"Dim LastRow As Long"
"LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row"
" For i = 1 To LastRow"
 " If ws.Cells(i, 5) = 0 Then GoTo NextIteration"
  "lstbox1.AddItem ws.Cells(i, 1).Value"
"lstbox1.List(i - 1, 1) = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value"
"lstbox1.List(i - 1, 2) = ws.Cells(i, 3).Value"
"lstbox1.List(i - 1, 3) = ws.Cells(i, 4).Value"
"lstbox1.List(i - 1, 4) = ws.Cells(i, 5).Value"
 "NextIteration:"
"Next i"
 "End Sub"

Comment: The Data sheet is just a simple table with with the Dim of A1 - E10. I have just filled the cells with arbitrary information except for E1-E10 these I put whole numbers in from 1 to 9 just to run the code. It is having the same issues as the actual tracking system I am working on.

Comment: Can you put your workbook somewhere on a transfer site (ex. [here](https://wetransfer.com/)) and add the link? I will work on it and solve the issue, when I will find some time...

Comment: I just tried your first adjusted my sample to use your first suggestion by adding another column with the formula 
"If (E2>0,E2,"") and ofcourse copping it down the whole column. This would give me the " If ws.Cells(i, 6)<> "" Then"

Comment: @TheTracker: But, it's a pity to find a work around when it should work without that... But, it is your choice. I wish you luck!

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TsMTFGSL7ccq2E4PyqlL4mUKls99wcfH/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The comment above is a link to the project on Google Drive

Comment: I prefer no work around,  I hate to be stumped like this. but with the lack of the Continue function I am not sure what else I can do.

Comment: The function in discussion cannot be continue! It iterates only up to LastRow. Please, check if it is correctly returned...